# Save a Twilio <Stream> of format 8Khz `mulaw` to a file

Tags: ffmpeg, twilio, resampling

There are a couple of posts that address the question, but I wasn't able to successfully playback a saved file. It usually plays back at half speed.

[Convert 8kHz mulaw to 16KHz PCM in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767373/convert-8khz-mulaw-to-16khz-pcm-in-real-time)

Using the accepted answer in the above question, I saved the raw and base64 decoded the audio in go:

```golang
// Media event
type Media struct {
    Track     string `json:"track"`
    Chunk     string `json:"chunk"`
    Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
    Payload   string `json:"payload"`
}

// SaveAudio will upgrade connection to websocket and save the audio to file
func SaveAudio(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    utility.DebugLogf("SaveAudio")
    c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }

    defer utility.SafeClose(c)
    inBuf := bytes.Buffer{}

    loop := true
    for loop == true {
        _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        utility.PanicIfErr(err)
        decMessage := TwilioWSSMessage{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(message, &decMessage)
        utility.PanicIfErr(err)

        switch decMessage.Event {
        case "connected":
            utility.DebugLogf("Connected a %s protocol version:%s", decMessage.Protocol, decMessage.Version)
        case "start":
            utility.DebugLogf("Starting audio stream: %#v", decMessage.Start)
        case "media":
            chunk, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(decMessage.Media.Payload)
            utility.PanicIfErr(err)
            _, err = inBuf.Write(chunk)
            utility.PanicIfErr(err)
        case "stop":
            utility.DebugLogf("Ending audio stream: %#v", decMessage.Stop)
            loop = false
        default:
            utility.LogWarningf("Unrecognized event type: %s", decMessage.Event)
            loop = false
        }
    }

    saveRaw(&inBuf)
}

func saveRaw(buf *bytes.Buffer) {
    rawOut, err := os.Create("out.ulaw")
    utility.PanicIfErr(err)

    _, err = rawOut.Write(buf.Bytes())
    utility.PanicIfErr(err)
}
```

Then I used `ffmpeg` to convert from `mulaw` to the default `pcm_s16le`:

```sh
ffmpeg -f mulaw -ar 8000 -ac 1 -i out.ulaw mulaw_decoded.wav
```

Then upsampled the audio from 8k->16k and play it with vlc:

```sh
ffmpeg -i mulaw_decoded.wav -ar 16000 upsampled.wav && vlc upsampled.wav
```

But it plays at half speed.

Ultimately I'd like to do it all in rust or go, but I can't even get it working locally with just ffmpeg.

Thanks in advance.

---

output of the above two `ffmpeg` operations combined with the suggested sox resampler:

cmd:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -f mulaw -ar 8000 -ac 1 -bits_per_raw_sample 8 -i testsamples/raw_mulaw_bytes -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 16000 upsampled.wav
```

output:

```sh
[mulaw @ 0x7fecc0814000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, mulaw, from 'testsamples/raw_mulaw_bytes':
  Duration: 00:00:20.74, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_mulaw (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x7fecc0505600] tb:1/8000 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:8000 chlayout:0x4
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 0x7fecc0505280] ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s16 r:8000Hz -> ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s16 r:16000Hz
Output #0, wav, to 'upsampled.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 pcm_s16le
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
size=     648kB time=00:00:20.74 bitrate= 256.0kbits/s speed=1.55e+03x
video:0kB audio:648kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.011753%
Input file #0 (testsamples/raw_mulaw_bytes):
  Input stream #0:0 (audio): 519 packets read (165920 bytes); 519 frames decoded (165920 samples);
  Total: 519 packets (165920 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (upsampled.wav):
  Output stream #0:0 (audio): 200 frames encoded (331840 samples); 200 packets muxed (663680 bytes);
  Total: 200 packets (663680 bytes) muxed
[AVIOContext @ 0x7fecc0433cc0] Statistics: 4 seeks, 6 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x7fecc042a6c0] Statistics: 165920 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

The audio sounds the same as before

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/253470/130459) provide a solution (especially see the last comment to it)?

Comment: On a side note, please do not ask question the way you did: the question as stated has nothing to do with Go and/or websockets and/or µ-law codec: it's purely about a particular problem with an attempt to upsample an audio file using `ffmpeg`, so ask it like this and tag it like this. If/when you'll have a problem with implementing something using Go as a programming language, please post a separate question tagged with `go`. This particular question contains no programming problem.

Comment: okay, thanks for the edit, no that answer did not solve it. same result with: `ffmpeg -y -i mulaw_decoded.wav -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 16000 upsampled.wav && vlc upsampled.wav` - I added the ffmpeg output to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out thanks to this answer: [Slow motion effect when decoding OPUS audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116447/slow-motion-effect-when-decoding-opus-audio-stream)

where he mentions:

> Another possible reason of "slow motion" is more than one stream decoded by the same decoder. But in this case you also get distorted slow audio.

so the tracks for this call are `inbound` and `outbound` so in `case "media":`
to save just one track:

```golang
if decMessage.Media.Track == "outbound" {
  chunk, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(decMessage.Media.Payload)
  utility.PanicIfErr(err)
  _, err = outboundBuf.Write(chunk)
  utility.PanicIfErr(err)
}
```

and the ffmpeg commands work as expected