# Why does collecting inbound and outbound audio create distorted audio?

Tags: python, audio, twilio

I'm trying to stream audio bytes into a shared buffer, and pass this through a transcription model. The audio's coming from a websocket sampled at 8kHz and mu-law encoded. I've managed to play a few seconds of audio to myself fine if I stream into separate separate audio buffers (`ibuffer` and `obuffer`) for inbound and outbound audio, but if I collect into a `shared` buffer the audio is really slow and delayed. Here is an extract from my testing code:

```
obuffer = b""
ibuffer = b""
shared = b""

while True:
    data = await queue.get()
    if data["event"] == "media":
        websocket_payload = data["media"]["payload"]
        chunk = audioop.ulaw2lin(base64.b64decode(websocket_payload), 2)
        if data["media"]["track"] == INBOUND:
            obuffer += chunk
        if data["media"]["track"] == OUTBOUND:
            ibuffer += chunk
        shared += chunk
```

I've been testing by collecting `obuffer`, `ibuffer` and `shared`, pickling the buffers, and then saving as `.wav` files and playing them on my machine. The separate buffers play fine, and can even be merged by simply averaging them which also plays fine - but why can't collecting them into a shared buffer produce the same quality of audio? The produced sound is quite far off from the original, and I've tried different sampling rates up to 16 kHz etc. Does anyone have any idea on what to do here?

It's strange because Twilio's [own documentation](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/transcribe-phone-calls-text-real-time-twilio-vosk#Streaming-and-transcribing-the-audio-from-the-call) says you can do this no problem.

```
import pickle
import wave

with open("all_bytes.pkl", "rb") as f:
    loaded_audio_bytes = pickle.load(f)

nchannels = 1
sampwidth = 2
framerate = 8000
nframes = len(loaded_audio_bytes) // (nchannels * sampwidth)

with wave.open("wav.wav", 'wb') as wf:
    wf.setnchannels(nchannels)
    wf.setsampwidth(sampwidth)
    wf.setframerate(framerate)
    wf.setnframes(nframes)
    wf.writeframes(loaded_audio_bytes)
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61000169/6067528) suggests just using the outbound only, but I need both tracks here!

Comment: For distortion it is usually going to be a problem with sample with / depth and number of channels rather than sample rate. If sample rate were the problem then the audio should just sound slower or quicker than it actually is. Try a test tone with a bit depth of 8 bits and only one channel. A simple sine tone should give you an indication as to what might be causing the distortion.

Comment: You say you have been [_pickling_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) the objects. I would recommend maybe in the first instance just trying to deal with the raw data.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are concatenating the audio chunks. You intent was joining those. Let me illustrate.

Let's mark the chunks from the input stream as `I0, I1, ...` and chunks from output stream as `O0, O1, O2, ...` and the resulting audio as `S0, S1, ...`.

What is happening now in your application is that chunks from the streams come in "random" order, so you get something like

```
S = [I0, I1, O0, I2, I3, O1, O2, O3, I4, O4 ... ]
```

As your chunks are short, you are percepting input and output audio streams interleaved as audio slow down (and distorted at the boundaries of chunks from different sources). If you would set the chunk duration to a several seconds you would clearly hear that phemonenon.

Your shared audio should be JOINED:

```
S0 = (I0 + O0)/2  << for each audio sample in the chunk
S1 = (I1 + O1)/2 
...
```

assuming the chunk duration of both streams are the same.
You can use `shared += audiloop.add(input_chunk, output_chunk)`, just make sure the chunks are timely aligned.

Comment: Thanks @igrinis - that's really helped my understanding, and confirms to me why collecting into separate buffers and taking the avg worked too. Tbh, since I get my audio chunks in sequence, I think i'll continue collecting them separately and averaging as otherwise I'll need to collect them two at a time, add them together and collect in a shared buffer, but your comment has truly helped my understanding so bounty has been awarded your way!

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason why your shared buffer produces poor-quality audio is that you are appending the chunks from both inbound and outbound tracks without any synchronization or alignment. This could result in overlapping or mismatched audio segments, which would cause distortion and delay.
You can use the soundfile module in Python, which can read and write audio files in various formats, including WAV and ULAW.

Here is a possible code snippet that uses soundfile to merge the inbound and outbound audio bytes into a shared buffer:

```
import soundfile as SF
import numpy as np
import io

# Initialize empty lists to store the audio data arrays
inbound_data = []
outbound_data = []

# Initialize an empty byte stream for the shared buffer
shared = io.BytesIO()

# Loop through the queue and get the data
while True:
   data = await queue.get()
   if data["event"] == "media":
       websocket_payload = data["media"]["payload"]
  chunk = audioop.ulaw2lin(base64.b64decode(websocket_payload), 2)
   if data["media"]["track"] == INBOUND:
  # Read the inbound chunk into a numpy array and append it to the inbound list
  data, samplerate = sf.read(io.BytesIO(chunk), format="RAW", 
  subtype="PCM_16", channels=1, samplerate=8000)
  inbound_data.append(data)
  if data["media"]["track"] == OUTBOUND:
  # Read the outbound chunk into a numpy array and append it to the outbound list
  data, samplerate = sf.read(io.BytesIO(chunk), format="RAW", subtype="PCM_16", channels=1, samplerate=8000)
  outbound_data.append(data)

  # Concatenate the inbound and outbound data arrays along the second axis
  combined_data = np.concatenate((inbound_data, outbound_data), axis=1)

  # Write the combined data to the shared buffer as a WAV file
     sf.write(shared, combined_data, samplerate=samplerate, format="WAV")
```

I hope this works fine for you. (There is useful link from StackOverflow community for this issue :[Why does collecting inbound and outbound audio create distorted audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78035674/can-only-stream-inbound-and-outbound-separately-with-twilio-media-stream))